# Layer in control software to abstract from real mechatronical system and simulation program

Tags: simulation, abstraction

It's about a mechatronical system that needs to be controlled via software. It is not yet clear in which language it will be written, but since it is not important, let's just say in Java.

The 1. thing is that we will need to send messages via CAN. So we have the control software, some event happens and we send a message via CAN. The mechatronical system will react.

Now the 2. thing is that obviously it would be good to be able to test the software without a real mechatronical system, since it reduces effort. So I thought about writing another program, a simulation program.

So I imagine that the simulation program notices when a CAN message is sent and reacts to it.

How is a good approach to accomplish that?

I mean for the real mechatronical system the control software needs to send a CAN message directly on the bus(, maybe via some native code). For the simulation program some kind of interprocess communication is needed. How must the control software be designed that it doesn't care if there is some simulation program that is listening or a real mechatronical system that gets the CAN messages?

My first thought was that the control software always sends "CAN messages" via an interprocess communication approach. Let's say for the sake of simplicity it is RMI. Then to send real CAN messages via the bus there is some module in the same control software that gets the "CAN messages" via RMI and forwarding them to the real CAN bus.
Now the simulation program is able to receive the "CAN messages" via RMI, too, and can react to it.

Is that a good approach? Because I see that there is some overhead in the control software by communicating to itself via interprocess communication, which is not neccessary in principle. But I see no other possibility to have an abstraction layer, such that I have no special code for the simulation program in the control software.

Thank you for feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You're describing one aspect of [Hardware-in-the-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-in-the-loop_simulation) testing.  It's a standard approach for developing mechatronic systems that combine software and hardware.

In a software setting one way to solve this problem is to provide an interface (as in a Java interface, rather than a physical one). You end up with two concrete implementations of that interface, one for your real hardware, and one for your test version. Because the real and test versions provide the same interface, they should be [interchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Once you've got your interfaces described how you implement them should be irrelevant (ie/ you could use a scripting language to develop the test code more quickly or cheaply) - so RPC may be a possibility, but there are certainly other choices.